# Calling the contents within a list in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, list, csv

So I have a website where the user puts a .csv file into a website and the website extracts it into a list in JavaScript. The full code that I am doing is to compare a .csv file that the user inputs into a website with the .csv file the website currently has. I want to be able to compare the two different files outside the function that I have below.

```
var a = [];
function compare(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsText(file);
    reader.onload = function(event) {
        var csv = event.target.result;
        var data = $.csv.toArrays(csv);
        number = data.length;
        for (i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {

            a.push({date: data[i][0], url: data[i][5], count: data[i][6]});
    };
    reader.onerror = function() {
        alert('Unable to read ' + file.fileName);
    };
}

var para = document.createElement("p");
var node = document.createTextNode(a[0].url);
para.appendChild(node);
var element = document.getElementById("demo");
element.appendChild(para);
```

At the end of this code snippet, I was testing to see if I can call upon the contents of the list a. However, I keep getting an "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined".

The error occurs at

```
var node = document.createTextNode(a[0].url);"
```

Comment: where is `compare` called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is the async nature of the FileReader

```
function compare(file, callback) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsText(file);
    reader.onload = function (event) {
        var a = [];
        var csv = event.target.result;
        var data = $.csv.toArrays(csv);
        number = data.length;
        for (i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
            a.push({
                date: data[i][0],
                url: data[i][5],
                count: data[i][6]
            });
            callback(a);
        };
    }
    //misplaced it in the onload handler
    reader.onerror = function () {
        alert('Unable to read ' + file.fileName);
    };
}
```

then need to use the callback to access `a`

```
//here compare is an async method so to use the value of a after calling compare we will have to depend on a callback
compare(e.target.files[0], function (a) {
    var para = document.createElement("p");
    var node = document.createTextNode(a[0].url);
    para.appendChild(node);
    var element = document.getElementById("demo");
    element.appendChild(para);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/290sf1z0/)